# Default duration of the page curl animation

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

I am using PageviewController for page flipping but animation is too fast. i want to increase animation duration ? How  can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/Dillion/iOS-Flip-Transform) you can find a good project with page flip animation and duration option may be helpfull for you.